# Dúvida strings pyhton

Tags: python-3.x, string, criptografia

Criei um algoritmo que encripta palavras e mensagens. Para funcionar ele precisa de uma chave numérica simples, como 9, 4, 2, onde a primeira letra vai ser deslocada 9 posições, a segunda 4, etc.

Tudo rodando perfeitamente com o código abaixo

```
import string

alfabeto = string.ascii_uppercase  
msg = 'sendmoremoney'
msg = msg.upper() 
chave = [9, 0, 1, 7, 23, 15, 21, 14, 11, 11, 2, 8, 9]
resultado = ""
posicao = 0

for letra_m in msg: 
    mod_a = (alfabeto.find(letra_m) + int(chave[posicao])) % 26 
    resultado += alfabeto[mod_a]
    posicao += 1
print(resultado)
pausa = input('\n')
```

Porém, se eu comento a linha `msg = msg.upper()` a sequência obtida com a resposta é uma outra bastante diferente.

Não entendi o porquê da resposta ser modificada ao eliminar aquela linha já que a resposta deveria ser baseada nos valores dentro da da variável `alfabeto`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Há alguns detalhes que você deve ser atentar:

- O alfabeto original que você está usando é o do módulo `string`, no caso o `string.ascii_uppercase`. O que lhe dá as letras do alfabeto em maiúsculas (*ABCDEF...*)
- Você está usando o método `.find` de string para encontrar a posição no alfabeto.

Acontece que como você está utilizando um alfabeto em letras maiúsculas, quando você procura pela posição de uma letra minúscula, o `find` te retorna `-1`, isto por que ele não encontrou, por exemplo, a letra **a** no alfabeto **ABCD...**.

### Como contornar isso?

Ao invés de transformar a frase inteira em maiúscula, converta apenas o caractere quando usar. Assim você pode ainda manter a frase no formato original. Eu só modifiquei 3 linhas, para ficar da seguinte maneira:

```py
import string

alfabeto = string.ascii_uppercase  
msg = 'sEnDmOrEmOnEy'
#msg = msg.upper() ==> Não mais necessário
chave = [9, 0, 1, 7, 23, 15, 21, 14, 11, 11, 2, 8, 9]
resultado = ""
posicao = 0

for letra_m in msg:
    mod_a = (alfabeto.find(letra_m.upper()) + int(chave[posicao])) % 26 
    resultado += alfabeto[mod_a] if letra_m.isupper() else alfabeto[mod_a].lower()
    posicao += 1
print(resultado)
pausa = input('\n')
```

Note que eu comentei o `msg.upper()`, mas converti depois o caractere separadamente na linha:

```py
mod_a = (alfabeto.find(letra_m.upper()) + int(chave[posicao])) % 26
```

Assim eu poderei fazer o que fiz na linha seguinte:

```py
resultado += alfabeto[mod_a] if letra_m.isupper() else alfabeto[mod_a].lower()
```

Onde eu verifiquei se antes o caractere estava maiúsculo ou minúsculo e depois mantive o estado dele. Explicando: como eu sei que no alfabeto eu vou encontra letras maiúsculas apenas eu ponho um `if letra_m.usupper()` para ver se ele já estava maísculo, assim não terei perdas. E no `else` apenas fiz o resultado ficar minúsculo caso o caractere estivesse assim.